# GHCI starts without Prelude

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I'm a beginner at Haskell and have the problem that when I start GHCI, Prelude is not automatically loaded. I used this command in my haskell lecture: `:set -NoImplicitPrelude` to avoid loading Prelude. But now I can't undo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:set -XImplicitPrelude` and then reload with `:reload` or `:r`.